# How to migrate this code in flutter from version 2.2.3 to latest version

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the code from [Github](https://github.com/dickyrey/newsapp), but the code version is an old version(Around version 2.2.3 to 2.8.1 ). I'm now on version 2.10.3. How do I migrate this code to a new version?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update this project to lastest mean to null safety then update the version in the dependencies in  pubspec.yaml file

[image: replace the 2.7.0 as in the image to whatever version you want to]

then run:

flutter clean

flutter pub get
flutter run

Answer (score 0):

**I will show you an easy way to migrate old code projects.**

Firstly, I recommend not working on the current old project; it is so painful. Instead, create a new project where you can put your old project code into new code at a time.
Simply put a line of code below on the old code project terminal.
`$ flutter create -t <project-type> <new-project-path>`

For example, your terminal code like, `PS C:\Users\habib\VScodeProject\git_ripository\simple-weather-old> flutter create -t app C:\Users\habib\VScodeProject\git_ripository\simple-weather-new`

If you want to see more about flutter migrating: [[See this flutter doc]](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration#what-if-i-cant-use-android-studio)